# MooTools: How do I make an object capture a custom event occured in its nested object?

Tags: javascript, events, mootools

Here's the simplified code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ParentDiv = new Class ({    
            initialize : function(htmlElement) {
                console.log('debug: parent object created');    
                $$('.childDiv').each(function(childDiv){
                    childDiv = new ChildDiv(childDiv);
                })    
                htmlElement.addEvents({
                    'click': function (){
                        console.log('debug: clicked parent');
                    },    
                    'testEvent' : function(){
                        console.log('debug: complex logic altering inner HTML of the element');
                    }
                })
            }
        });

        function initParent () {
            $$('.parentDiv').each(function(parentDiv){parentDiv = new ParentDiv(parentDiv);})
        }

        var ChildDiv = new Class ({
            initialize : function(htmlElement) {
                console.log('debug: child object created');
                htmlElement.addEvent('click', function (){
                    console.log('debug: clicked child');
                    this.addEvent('testEvent', function(){console.log('debug: grabbed an event in child element, fired by child element')})
                    this.fireEvent('testEvent');
                })
            }


        });

        document.addEvent('domready', function(){
            initParent();
        });


    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="parentDiv">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div class="childDiv">Clicky Thingy</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The outcome is the following: neither of the events are grabbed by parent object's event listeners, while capturing the events is something I'm trying to achieve. A possible occurance of such structure: we have a bunch of control elements on the page, they all fire their own events, while the document or any other kind of container manipulates the content within based on the captured event's type.

So, is there a way to make 'debug: complex logic altering inner HTML of the element' appear in the console box with the use of custom events?

Comment: I would register only one click listener for the whole document. once fired you can traverse the dom upwards beginning at the target element. You can test if the current element has a »childDiv« or »parentDiv« class to filter out your desired html elements.

Comment: `htmlElement.addEvent('click', function (){` -> `this` === `htmlElement` - not your instance. you need to bind it or pass a reference to bubble the event to the instance. as it stands, you are firing an event on the dom element itself.

Comment: @philipp the `click` event was added just for the ease of debug, while, as I've described, my problem is to make custom events work, when the custom event is fired by an element within one object and captured by an element within another object

Comment: @DimitarChristoff from what I understand, conventionally, events are fired from DOM elements, and the event listeners should be attached to them as well: I don't have any trouble with that. If I bind the `addEvent` to `this`, I'll be calling the method in relation to the class, while I just want to be able to capture a custom event by adding an event listener inside `initialize` function body of a class. I couldn't get that to work and I don't know why, which is why I came here :)

Comment: firing synthetic events through elements across different class instances that have no knowledge of each other is not a good pattern. you should fire your events on your class instances and separate it out, passing the element as an argument to the event callbacks. you can also subscribe to events on all childDiv instances from the parentDiv instance (or vice versa).

Comment: @DimitarChristoff from my question: "A possible occurance of such structure: we have a bunch of control elements on the page, they all fire their own events, while the document or any other kind of container manipulates the content within based on the captured event's type." that's the kind of behavior that I'm trying to implement. Also, though the ChildDiv object doesn't know about the ParentDiv object, ChildDiv is created within ParentDiv, so he obviously know somthing ;)

Comment: the semantic issue here is this. you have an actual class that represents all your relevant elements. it should curry all logic. even though an element is a child element, it should NOT care at all about any parents or siblings - just emit events and let whoever is interested to subscribe. the parentDiv instance is more like your controller, managing the children - hence it knows who they are and has the ability to pub/sub to them. i see what you are trying to do, but this does not scale so well imo.

Comment: @DimitarChristoff the problem is, I can't find a way to subscribe :) "So, is there a way to make 'debug: complex logic altering inner HTML of the element' appear in the console box with the use of custom events?" - run th code, at this point the message will never be shown :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot wrong with this. To make you life easier, dont use so many nested anonymous functions, they work, but make it hard to untangle sometimes. I cleaned it up and made you a fiddle so you can see how this may work.

http://jsfiddle.net/WQCDd/

You need to learn about event binding to do what you want: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Also, you were not implementing the "events" on the class so you cant do this.fireevent

A good start to almost any mootools class will look like this:

```
var ClassName = new Class({
        Implements: [Options, Events],

    options: {

    },


    initialize: function(options){      
        this.setOptions(options);   
    }
});
```

Comment: I've taken the tips into account, thank you for your attention. After this question has been around for a while I went to MooTools IRC, and got my answer there. Everything you said is true, yet the one thing that I needed to hear to keep going was that I used the fireEvent method wrong: it doesn't fire the event FROM the element, but it fires an event TO the element instead, if that's the right way of putting it. So all I've had to do to make the parent capture an event was to write `parentDiv.fireEvent('testEvent')` somewhere within the child class definition.